# Moshi Custom JsonAdapter

Tags: json, rx-java, rx-android, moshi

I am trying to create a custom `JsonAdapter` for my JSON data that would bypass the serialization of specific field. Following is my sample JSON:

```
{
  "playlistid": 1,
  "playlistrows": [
    {
      "rowid": 1,
      "data": {
        "123": "title",
        "124": "audio_link"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON field `data` in above have dynamic key numbers, so I want to bypass this data field value and return `JSONObject`.

I am using `RxAndroid`, `Retrofit2` with `Observables`. I have created a service class:

```
public static <S> S createPlaylistService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(baseURL)
           .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
           .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
           .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create());

    return builder.build().create(serviceClass);
}
```

I am calling this service using observable like this:

```
@GET("http://www.mylink.com/wp-json/subgroup/{subgroupId}/playlist/{comboItemId}")
Observable<Playlist> getPlaylist(@Path("subgroupId") int subgroupId, @Path("comboItemId") int comboItemId);
```

Then I run it like this:

```
ServiceBuilder.createPlaylistService(FHService.class).getPlaylist(123, 33);
```

My Pojo classes look like this:

```
public class Playlist {

    @Json(name = "playlistid")
    public Long playlistid;
    @Json(name = "playlistrows")
    public List<Playlistrow> playlistrows = null;

}
public class Playlistrow {
    @Json(name = "rowid")
    public Long rowid;
    @Json(name = "data")
    public Object data;
}
```

The problem is it would return a `data` value in this format:

```
{
 123=title,
 124=audio_link
}
```

which is invalid to parse as `JSONObject`.

I have Googled a lot and have also checked some `Moshi` example recipes but I had got no idea about how to bypass this specific field and return valid JSONObject, since I am new to this `Moshi` library.

Comment: The org.json APIs are pretty unfriendly. Have you considered making the type of data a regular map like Map<Integer, String>?

Comment: @EricCochran Never thought it was that easy and I spend my entire night in experimenting with custom `JsonAdapter`... Thanks a lot!